# Cmake and Visual Studio 17 2022 generator - how to export compile commands?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have a C++ project which is compiled on Windows 10 using cmake and Visual Studio 17 2022 generator. That generator doesn't support exporting compile commands using the following command:

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

Do you know other way to export compile commands which work with VS generator ? Maybe I can find compile commands somewhere in the cmake cache ?

Comment: Why not use a different generator once just to get the commands?

Comment: It's not possible. You could use Ninja and still use Visual Studio as a compiler, but without any solution files.